# snakemake cant get lambda return in params

Tags: lambda, bioinformatics, snakemake

I have a snakemake params like:

```
def get_papreDE(config, super_group): 
    gtf_config = []
    for sample_name in sample.keys(): 
        group_data=sample[sample_name][0]
        super_group_data=sample[sample_name][3]
        if super_group == super_group_data or super_group == 'all':
            stringtie_gtf = config['output']['stringtie_gtf'].format(sample=sample_name, output=output, group=group_data)
            gtf_config.append("\t".join([sample_name, stringtie_gtf]))
    return gtf_config

rule prepDE:
    input: 
        gtf = lambda wildcards: get_stringtie_gtf(config, wildcards.group)
    output:
        counts = output_data['prepDE_counts']
    params: 
        input_gtf = lambda wildcards: get_papreDE(config, wildcards.group), 
    threads: 9
    log: 
        log = 'log/' + output_data['prepDE_counts'] + '.log'
    shell: 
        """
            prepDE.py -i <(echo "{params.input_gtf}" | sed 's/ /\\n/g') -o {output.counts} > {log} 2>&1
        """
```

I want this script to generate input table for  prepDE.py, but the `{params.input_gtf}` in shell always null, the finally shell to run is like:

```
prepDE.py -i <(echo "" | sed 's/ /\\n/g') -o /path/to/output.csv > /path/to/log 2>&1
```

I have checked the function is work well by directly print `gtf_config` before function return value

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong without some data. Try posting a reproducible example or put some `print` statements inside `get_papreDE` to see what goes wrong. Perhaps `sample.keys()` has zero length or the `if` condition is never true.

Comment: Its a lit hard to make a reproducible example because It a part of a large pipeline, I have `print(gtf_config)` and check its value is ok,  so I dont know how to debug it, we have worked to bypass this issue with convert `get_papreDE` to a python script in section `run`  at another rule, and output to a temp file as the input of  `prepDE`, It work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because params is expecting a string, not a list.  Try to change your return to `return ' '.join(gtf_config)` (or `'\n'.join` and skip the sed process).  It would also be prudent to raise an error if the list is empty prior to returning.